# How can we use javascript to tokenise a piece of text?

Tags: javascript

Consider this expression in a programming language:

```
x = a + b * 2;
```

The lexical analysis of this expression yields the following sequence of tokens:

```
[
    (identifier, x),
    (operator, =),
    (identifier, a),
    (operator, +),
    (identifier, b),
    (operator, *),
    (literal, 2),
    (separator, ;)
]
```

In short, we break a mathematical equation into tokens like `x`, `=`, `a`, `+`, `b`, `*`, `2`

Now I need to tokenize piece of text and the program should return output as tokens.
I have tried to return output as tokens but it didn't work.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE. Show the result of your investigation with actual input and expected output. For now it looks like you just want `"some text to be tokenized".split(" ')`

Comment: This awfully looks like homework you are not putting an effort on. What @mplungjan said is correct, you should post your code attempts first.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of modules out there which provides javascript tokenizer functionality.

For example with esprima module you can do it like this:

```
var esprima = require('esprima')

esprima.tokenize('answer = 42')

[ 
  { type: 'Identifier', value: 'answer' },
  { type: 'Punctuator', value: '=' },
  { type: 'Numeric', value: '42' } 
]
```

Also checkout this snippet somebody wrote: https://gist.github.com/shalvah/2a4c6e34353c26f8ab6d26fcd2bcca8f#file-tokenizer-js